# Get NaN instead of id value in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I try to get element id using jquery, but instead of id I have a NaN, can anybody help me?

```
<button class="editResume" type="button" id="editResume1">Edit</button>

$(function () {
        $(".editResume").click(function () {
            var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(6));
            alert(id);
        });
    });
```

Comment: `var id = parseInt(this.id.replace(/\D/g,''), 10)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `10` instead of `6` since the number is staying at *10<sup>th</sup>* index:

```
var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(10));
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/74Vqp/3/)**

Another alternative solution here is to apply regex:

```
$(function () {
    $(".editResume").click(function () {
        var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/),10);
        alert(id);
    });
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/74Vqp/1/)**

Comment: Actually substring will work with multiple digits too.

Comment: @CatalinMunteanu Yes, you're correct. I've updated regex as an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `10` instead of `6` in [substring(indexA[, indexB])](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) also you can give end index

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/8yj74/1/)**

```
var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(10));
```

Answer (score 0):

If only the number from id value changes you can get it by using

```
var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(10));
```

'editResume1'.substring(6) is actually 'sume1'

Answer (score 0):

```
var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').substring(10));
```

But why do you want do it in this way?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to append some (number or id of the table) in the attribute id always seperate it with some character (say `-`).
eg. `id='editResume-1'`. Then in jQuery.

`var id = $(this).attr('id').split('-').pop()` will give back your number. It works for every case even if you id is `id='edit1Resume-1` or `id='5-edit-resume-1` or any. Remember to append your required number/id at the end seperated by `-`

I always prefer this way. May be useful (yn)

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice method also to get the digit if the number is always present at the end

```
var id = parseInt($(this).attr('id').slice(-1));
```

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/74Vqp/2/)